# Connecting routes, views and controllers (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails so please pardon my amateur mistakes, but I've been stuck for about an hour or two and have made negative progress.

> Goal:
>
> From the user `profile` view, link to a form that allows this `user`
>   to change their email. Once the form is submitted, it should trigger
>   an appropriate method within the `user controller`.

I can handle the rest, I just haven't managed to connect the parts mentioned above. I have been reading [railsTutorial.org](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-the_form_html) and [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) but haven't been able to understand `routing` `form_for()` sufficiently.

User Profile Link:

`<%= @user.email %> <%= link_to "(change)", email_path(@user) %>`

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get    'email'    => 'users#email_form'
  post   'email'    => 'users#changeemail'
end
```

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def email_form
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def changeemail
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @user
  end
end
```

Currently the error I get once I click the link is `Couldn't find User with 'id'=` which I assume means user ID is nil because I fail at passing it.

I would greatly appreciate an explanation of what data is being passed through this workflow so I can be a better developer, thank you very much!

EDIT:

The form itself:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: user_path(@user))  do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :new_email %>
  <%= f.text_field :new_email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit New Email", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this (note :id and "as"):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get    'email/:id'    => 'users#email_form', as :email
  post   'email/:id'    => 'users#changeemail', as :change_email
end
```

The :id is then expected to be part of the route.

Alternatively, pass the id directly when generating the url:

```
<%= @user.email %> <%= link_to "(change)", email_path(id: @user) %>
```

---

This will make a call to "UsersController#update"

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: user_path(@user))  do |f| %>
```

...instead you would use something like::

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: change_email_path(@user), method: :put)  do |f| %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

---

...but in terms of best practices, if you want to do separate flow for email updating, you could be more explicit in treating it as a different resource (even though it's still the user record).

For example, you could map these to an explicit 'resource' with a #show and #update action...

Routes:

```
resources :user_emails, only: [:show, :update]
```

Controller:

```
class UserEmailsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @user # goes back to UsersController#show
  end
end
```

Then the route would be:

```
<%= @user.email %> <%= link_to "(change)", user_email_path(@user) %>
```

In this case we don't have to say (id: @user) since the 'resource' generates the right urls for you.

...and this would be

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: user_email_path(@user), method: :post)  do |f| %>
```

Comment: What should the file containing the form be named and should it still be in `views/users/form` for this to render it. NVM However I edited my question since I realized I was missing the `form_for`!

Comment: It would follow the same pattern: "/views/user_emails/show.html.erb"

Comment: How do I send the form to `userEmails.update`? since your current final answer is not best practice :| Getting `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UserEmailController):`

Comment: adding an `s` to the end of `:user_email` in `resources :user_email, only: [:show, :update]` made everything work, thanks!